# Using Google maps with Xamarin on Windows

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.windows

Is it possible to use Google maps on Windows?

I'm familiar with Xamarin.Forms.Maps but it uses Bing maps on Windows.  Is there a way to use Google maps on both operating systems?  If not is the cause technical or legal (licensing issues)?

Comment: It is convoluted, technically Google provides `Web Services` and `JavaScript` APIs so platform support is not an issue. But once you get outside of the "free" Android & iOS native app usage and their Maps' `Standard Plan Terms of Service` , TOS changes, licensing kicks in and there are pricing plans for each of the different Maps APIs.... Does not mean you can not do it yourself, W10 apps like `Maps App Discovery` use the Google APIs.... Licensing, pricing, TOS, etc... all are available at: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we can't.

Because Google does not provide "Native" maps SDK for Windows.
They has native maps SDK only for Android and iOS or some API for the web.